# Is possible to load shared-library in mememory ? And access funtion from it?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I am working on a project that can dynamically load a library. But, I have to prevent the deletion of the .so file. Is it possible to load this file in memory with std::memcpy and execute function from it ?

Thanks !

Comment: On which platform (Windows, Linux, your original OS, etc.)?

Comment: yes sorry I forget, on linux

Comment: Yes, indeed it is possible - after all, this is all `dlopen` is doing. But, this is no simple task. You'd have to resolve all the relocatable symbols before you can start executing, and I can't believe you will achieve anything.

Comment: Use [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Comment: @christopher - It is a totally different matter _to prevent the deletion of the .so file_, which doesn't belong to this question. Besides that, deletion of the .so file after dlopen won't hurt on Linux.

Comment: Use a static library (.a). Shared library (.so) is meant to be in a separate file, which is meant to be available when the program starts (but once loaded, the .so file itself may be deleted - the actual inode won't disappear until the program ends - this is how the POSIX filesystem works).